How to Access Headers in a GlobalKTable in Kafka Streams
I am trying to use a GlobalKTable to store data from a Kafka topic during the startup of my application. Both the GlobalKTable and KStream consume the same topic, I need to access headers in the GlobalKTable for processing. After the initial data load, my KStream will handle real-time records. these realtime record may be new record or exist in GlobalKTable. The challenge is that I can't access the Kafka headers in the GlobalKTable configuration. Here's a summary of my setup:
Two configuration classes: one for GlobalKTable and one for KStream.
I need to initialize KStream after GlobalKTable is fully loaded.
Here’s the GlobalKTableConfig class where I want to access the headers:
@Bean(name = "createGlobalKTable")
public GlobalKTable<String, GenericRecord> createGlobalKTable(@Qualifier("globalKTableStreamsBuilder") StreamsBuilderFactoryBean globalKTableStreamsBuilderFactoryBean) throws Exception {
    StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = globalKTableStreamsBuilderFactoryBean.getObject();
    Map<String, String> serdeConfig = new HashMap<>();
    serdeConfig.put("schema.registry.url", schemaRegistryUrl);
    serdeConfig.put("schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info", basicAuthUserInfo);
    serdeConfig.put("schema.registry.basic.auth.credentials.source", basicAuthCredentialsSource);

    final Serde<GenericRecord> valueGenericAvroSerde = new GenericAvroSerde();
    valueGenericAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false);

    return streamsBuilder.globalTable(ediLegTopic,
         Materialized.<String, GenericRecord, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(storeName + "-global")
             .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
             .withValueSerde(valueGenericAvroSerde));

}

an this is KstreamConfig Class:
    @Bean
    public StreamsBuilderFactoryBean kStreamBuilder(
        @Qualifier("kafkaStreamsConfig") KafkaStreamsConfiguration config,
        GlobalKTableService globalKTableService) {
        StreamsBuilderFactoryBean factoryBean = new StreamsBuilderFactoryBean(config, new CleanupConfig(false, false));
        factoryBean.setKafkaStreamsCustomizer(kafkaStreams -> {
            kafkaStreams.setStateListener((newState, oldState) -> {
                log.info("State changed from " + oldState + " to " + newState);
                if (newState == KafkaStreams.State.RUNNING) {
                    KeyValueIterator<String, GenericRecord> keyValueIterator = globalKTableService.getAllValuesFromGlobalKTable();
                   // process each record regarding the logic
                }
            });
        });
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public KStream<String, GenericRecord> createKStream(
        @Qualifier("kStreamBuilder") StreamsBuilderFactoryBean kStreamsBuilderFactoryBean) throws Exception {
        StreamsBuilder kStreamBuilder = kStreamsBuilderFactoryBean.getObject();

        Map<String, String> serdeConfig = new HashMap<>();
        serdeConfig.put("schema.registry.url", schemaRegistryUrl);
        serdeConfig.put("schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info", basicAuthUserInfo);
        serdeConfig.put("schema.registry.basic.auth.credentials.source", basicAuthCredentialsSource);

        final Serde<GenericRecord> valueGenericAvroSerde = new GenericAvroSerde();
        valueGenericAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false);
        KStream<String, GenericRecord> kStream = kStreamBuilder.stream(ediLegTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), valueGenericAvroSerde));

        StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, GenericRecord>> storeBuilder = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
            Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(storeName + "-global"),
            Serdes.String(),
            valueGenericAvroSerde
        );
        kStreamBuilder.addStateStore(storeBuilder);

        KStream<String, GenericRecord> processedStream = kStream.process(() -> new CustomProcessor(globalKTableService, logicProvider), storeName + "-global");
        return processedStream;
    }
}

I have a processor to apply the logic for each realtime record:

public class CustomProcessor implements Processor<String, GenericRecord, String, GenericRecord> {
    private ProcessorContext<String, GenericRecord> context;
    private final GlobalKTableService globalKTableService;
    private final LogicProvider logicProvider;

    public CustomProcessor(GlobalKTableService globalKTableService, LogicProvider logicProvider) {
        this.globalKTableService = globalKTableService;
        this.logicProvider= logicProvider;
    }
    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext<String, GenericRecord> context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void process(Record<String, GenericRecord> processingRecord) {
        String key = processingRecord.key();
        GenericRecord value = processingRecord.value();
        Headers headers = processingRecord.headers();

        GenericRecord globalTableValue = globalKTableService.getValueFromGlobalKTable(key);

        if ((!value.equals(globalTableValue))) {
            log.info("No match in GlobalKTable. Forwarding stream record with key: {}", key);
            logicProvider.applyLogic(new KeyValue<>(key, value), headers);
            context.forward(processingRecord.withValue(value));
        } else {
            log.info("Match found in GlobalKTable for key: {}. Skipping forward.", key);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        log.info("Closing CustomProcessor");
    }
}

How can I access the Kafka headers in the GlobalKTable configuration?
This link Kafka Streams GlobalKTable and accessing the record headers has a related topic, but I cannot understand what does it mean.

KTables and GlobalKTables do not store header information, but only key, value, and record timestamp.
To be able to access the headers, you would need to pre-process the data to  copy the headers into the value. Such a pre-processing step implies that you read the original topic, and write the modified data back into a second topic, and populate the GlobalKTable from the second topic.
If using a second topic is a concern, you should be able to avoid it, if you are using Kafka Streams 3.8+. You can use addGlobalStore() (instead of globalTable() which is only syntactic sugar on top of addGlobalStore()) and implement a custom Processor that put() the data into the global store -- this allows you to add the headers on-the-fly before calling put()).
